# How to store updated rows in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a replace of OUTPUT/RETURNING clause in SNOWFLAKE.

Test scenario:
I have a metadata tbl, in which I store all tables + columns which should be updated:

| tblToUpdate | FieldToUpdate |
| --- | --- |
| tblA | name |
| tblA | lastname |
| tblB | middlename |
| tblC | address |
| tblC | phone |
| tblC | zipcode |

I dynamically generate the upd stmt, based on this table and it looks like :

```
update tblA set name = '#tst', lastname = '#tst';
update tblB set middlename = '#tst';
update tblC set address = '#tst', phone ='#tst', zipcode = '#tst';
```

Next step is to create a log table, to store the names of the updated tables + ids of updated rows.
How can I do this without creating a STREAM tbl for each tbl to be updated (metadata tbl can contain from 1 to n tables, rows from it can change above the time). I need to find a way to create the log table, to keep a track of all changed tables with its rows.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to write a stored procedure to do this

Comment: any ideas on how to start and what to log? from where to take the updated rows if not from streams table? thanks